# UIAlertView And UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I am using SWIFT in xcode 6 to develope my application AND needs to support the APP for iphone 4 and later versions... So have selected the '**Deploment Target**' as **7.1**. In simple words needs to support iOS7, iOS8 AND iOS9...

When using Alert View I came across in many places discussing now we have to use newly introduced '**UIAlertController**' rather than the old '**UIAlertView**'...

By reading got to know UIAlertView is deprecated from ios 8.

But in my case as I have to support for ios 7.1 AND I can NOT only use 'UIAlertController'.

I started using as the following way as many tutorials explains...

```
if (objc_getClass("UIAlertController") != nil)
{
    // Use UIAlertController
}
else
{
    // Use UIAlertView
}
```

But in this way got to write the same code twice and really annoyiong... Either I have to create a custom Alertview combining both or needs to continue coding like this....

but just to test I've used only `UIAlertView` (ignoring UIAlertController) and the app runs fine even in ios 8 simulators... But the document says UIAlertView is **deprecated** from iOS 8.0...

**So my question is**, Like to hear what the best practice to continue my app with these API changes... Is it alright if I ignore 'UIAlertController' and work with old 'UIAlertView' until stop support for iOS7 one day... Will that effect in to my app in any way bad? Thanks

Comment: `UIAlertView` works just fine with iOS 8 and 9. That's an option - just use `UIAlertView`. Once your app drops support for iOS 7, you can switch over to use just `UIAlertViewController`.

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258693/uialertview-changes-to-landscape-when-app-is-locked-in-portrait-only-in-ios8/26261120#26261120

Comment: Hi rmaddy, Yes that's what I thought as well. To use UIAlertView (ignoring the UIAlertController) as needs to support ios 7.1 at the moment... But as the document says UIAlertView is deprecated from iOS 8.0, completely confussed... Why they say like that if it works ok in  later versions as well ?

Comment: Hi iAnurag, yes was doing sort of a check like that to determine if UIAlertController is available... But my problem is why do we need to do separate check like this if UIAlertView works fine in ios 8 and 9. I know it's easy to use UIAlertController but implementing both obviousely is NO POINT as long as UIAlertView works fine with later versions (just writing same code 2 times).... I need to know how good it is to ignore using UIAlertController and use UIAlertView until completely stop support for IOS 7... The same thing 'rmaddy' says

Comment: uialertview has orientation issues in ios 8. thats why prefer to use uialertcontroller

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean "removed". It just means that it *could* be removed in the future. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301439/what-happens-if-an-api-your-app-uses-is-deprecated-after-your-app-is-released). I would go ahead and stick with `UIAlertView` until you de-support iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks  zpasternack. I will stick with UIAlertView until complelety stop support iOS 7...

Answer (score 0):

I've written a wrapper around these two classes which uses appropriate classes according to iOS version.

find it here

https://github.com/amosavian/ExtDownloader/blob/master/Utility%2BUI.swift

to show a simple alert use this:

```
 Utility.UI.alertShow("message", withTitle: "title", viewController: self);
```

to show an action view: use this code:

```
let buttons = [Utility.UI.ActionButton(title: "Say Hello", buttonType: .Default, buttonHandler: { () -> Void in
        print("Hello")
    })]
Utility.UI.askAction("message", withTitle: "title", viewController: self, anchor: Utility.UI.AnchorView.BarButtonItem(button: uibarbuttontapped), buttons: buttons)
```

In case you are presenting action in iPhone, it will add a cancel button automatically. But you can have custom cancel button by defining a button with type of ".Cancel"

If you want show a modal alert view, use this code:

```
let cancelBtn = Utility.UI.AlertButton(title: "Cancel", buttonType: .Cancel, buttonHandler: nil)
let okBtn = Utility.UI.AlertButton(title: "OK", buttonType: .Default, buttonHandler: { (textInputs) -> Void in
            print("OK button pressed")
})
Utility.UI.askAlert("message", withTitle: "title", viewController: self, buttons: [cancelBtn, okBtn], textFields: nil)
```

As you can see, the text fields is set to nil above. You can set it if you want ask something from user, like this:

```
let cancelBtn = Utility.UI.AlertButton(title: "Cancel", buttonType: .Cancel, buttonHandler: nil)
let okBtn = Utility.UI.AlertButton(title: "OK", buttonType: .Default, buttonHandler: { (textInputs) -> Void in
        print("You entered" + textInputs[0])
    }
})
let textFields = [Utility.UI.AlertTextField(placeHolder: "enter secret text here", defaultValue: "", textInputTraits: TextInputTraits.secretInput())]
Utility.UI.askAlert("Enter password", withTitle: "title", viewController: self, buttons: [cancelBtn, okBtn], textFields: textFields)
```

You can customize almost everything. e.g by defining custom textInputTrait you can customize text inputs easily. also you have not to deal with delegates, instead simple closures are there. Please read code to find out more.