# Show an UIAlertController from a button on an UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

This is what I coded inside a button in a `UITableViewCell`.

```
var shareAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Post Alert", 
    message: "Your Post has been Shared with your Friends", 
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

var Ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", 
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
    handler: nil)

shareAlert.addAction(Ok)
shareAlert.presentViewController(shareAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When the user clicks the button I want it to show this alert, but the app crashes as soon as I click the button. Am I doing it wrong? How do I show an alert view from a button in a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: What error does it produce when it crashes?

Comment: First of all, UIAlertController is only available on iOS 8+, so use UIAlertView when you're running on iOS 7. Second: Could you please post the code for setting up the button? Or is your code snippet part of an IBAction that is connected to the button?

Comment: Use a delegate on the cell. Instead of performing an action directly, let the controller which owns the table view perform the action.

Comment: @oliver yes my code snippet part of an IBAction that is connected to the button. and i am using IOS8

Comment: how to use a delegate? @Sulthan help me give me some coding..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It crashed because of this line

```
shareAlert.presentViewController(shareAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

A controller cannot present itself, so

Replace

```
shareAlert.presentViewController(shareAlert, ...)
```

by

```
yourCurrentViewController.presentViewController(shareAlert, ...)
```

And you should not use UIAlertView because it was deprecated in iOS 9 and maybe obsoleted in the next iOS, so use UIAlertController and you don't have to change it in near future

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574681/5304286

You can call alertShow function in this file to show simple message by the way:

```
 Utility.UI.alertShow("message", withTitle: "title", viewController: self)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `UIAlertController` you can use `UIAlertView`, like this:

```
 var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Post Alert", message: "Your Post has been Shared with your Friends", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok")
 alert.show()
```

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html

**Note:**

`UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 9.

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 9.